# SSIS multiple sources to a single derived column

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is it possible to have multiple sources (OLE DB) to go through the same derived column and the like? My current setup is have multiple control flows with same derived columns/splits/sorts etc. which output to the same destination but the only difference is the source. It is difficult to modify these derived columns as I have to do it a few times (5) which may lead to mistakes.

One solution I have explored previously was to use dynamic sql so I can use 1 source and multiple variables, but given the complexity of my queries I'd rather avoid this.

Comment: You combine (UNION) data sources into one data flow but only if they have mostly the same fields

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks. All my fields are the same despite being pulled from different tables.

Comment: @Kustomize you have to accept Nick answer if it solved the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use the `UNION ALL` component. If all your data sources have the same fields and data types, then feed them into a union all component then apply the column transformations to the output.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/union-all-transformation